# how identify touch in a particular view

Tags: iphone, uitouch

How to get touch on a particular view.

I am using

```
CGPoint Location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view ];
```

but want to trigger the action only if an particular subView is clicked.
How to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer myself...but thanks other which helped me on this

here it is

```
UITouch *touch ;
touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];


    if ([touch view] == necessarySubView)
{
//Do what ever you want
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
//here enable the touch
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yoursubview_Name.frame, touchLocation)) {
        //Your logic
        NSLog(@" touched");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a subclass (or create a category) of UIView and override the

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

where redirect the message to the appropriate delegate.

Comment: no you need not to do that...check my own answer which i found just few minutes ago...

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: +1 ..good alternate ,if large work to be done on a subview, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// here Tiles is a separate class inherited from UIView Class
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[Tiles class]]) {
        NSLog(@"[touch view].tag = %d", [touch view].tag);
    }
}
```

like this you can find view or subview is touched

Answer (score 1):

Heres a swift3 version without multitouch:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first, self.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try

```
CGPoint Location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:necessarySubView ];
```