# Get image name from touchesEnded

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, touchesended

In my storyboard I have a few images that are "User Interaction Enabled". 
In the `UIViewController` I override the `touchesEnded` function.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

Is it possible for me to get the name of the image that was clicked in this function? I would prefer not to `@IBOutlet` the images.

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't like to use IBOutlet for the images? Is the view dynamic, or is the layout the same each time it's displayed?

Comment: @stephen Its a mix of static images and dynamic images within a stackview.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192999/1718685 you should be able to determine the view below the touch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible exactly like you want it. Image views don't retain the file they loaded the image from, just the image data itself. But I assume you're setting the image names in IB and trying to get that name after a touch event, in that case you could set the image name in the element's restoration ID and retrieve the name via the restorationIdentifier property of the touched element.

You can get the touched element like this:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch: UITouch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        let touchedView = self.view.hitTest(location, with: event)

        print(touchedView.restorationIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Note that you have to set the image file name twice if you want to do it like this, and change the value twice when making changes. What you are trying smells of bad design, so if there's another way I'd go with that.

Comment: How would I retreive that restoriation ID in touchesEnded?

Answer (score 0):

if i got your question right, you dont wanna use `@IBOutlet`, but need to get the name of image clicked. So for this you can also give `tag` to `UIImageView` to identify them, and later can access any info.

first from **storyboard**, assign `1` or any int value to `tag` property and check `User Interaction Enabled` for `ImageView`.

Replace touchesEnded with the following lines-

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch: UITouch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
            if let touchedView = self.view.hitTest(location, with: event) as? UIImageView {
                if touchedView.tag == 1 {
                    debugPrint(touchedView.image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what do you mean to mention that **Please dont downvote it**. there is not allow to mention that kind of metnion in answer. if you are not sure about your answer then just add a comment.

Comment: How would I retreive that tag in touchesEnded?

Comment: @NitinGohel i am new here, so don't know much, and i would've added commnt but it needs 50 reputation.

Comment: @Maanu whatever you need 50repo it deos't mean you ask some one to do up vate or down vote.